# Interpretation of Kruskal Wallis post-hoc pairwise comparisons - SPSS

Tags: spss, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

I've run a KW test on my set on non-parametric data in SPSS, the output of the test giving me a p-value <0.05. As I have 20+ groups in my data set, I'm interested to see which group significantly differs from another. For this I've selected the all pairwise post hoc test, showing the different significant levels when comparing each group with each other. Now I have the pairwise graph, and I'm just a bit puzzled on how to interpret it. Can I say that the group with the highest rank is the most significantly different from the others (here gold with an average rank of 193, followed by silver etc) ?

[image]

Note that the labels of each group are fictitious but the data behind is accurate. I've looked around for the interpretation of pairwise graph but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: I recommend you to go to Help - Topics - Case Studies - Base - Nonparemetric tests. It will guide through interpreting such analyses.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to define "most significantly different" to answer this question. I'd recommend looking at the adjusted significance levels in the table of pairwise comparisons to get more detail.